# How to use Cursor? The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot

Tags: android, cursor

```
   Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
....

 public void onClick(View v) {
                    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                    int count = cursor.getCount();
                    //cursor.close();
                    tvContactCount.setText("Count: " + count);
                }
```

When clicked, I am getting log of

```
02-29 13:26:48.356: E/CursorWindow(5357): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 216, freeSpace() = 109, numRows = 2594
02-29 13:26:48.356: E/CursorWindow(5357): not growing since there are already 2594 row(s), max size 1048576
02-29 13:26:48.356: E/CursorWindow(5357): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 2593
02-29 13:26:48.356: E/Cursor(5357): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 2593
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Update: This line is throwing that error,   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

Comment: is this the issue? Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Do not call close on a managed query, since it does it for you. I'm actually not sure what the error is, but try removing the close statement and see what happens.

Comment: removing close is not helpful. Because What is happening is Cursor can handle upto 1 MB of data. i.e; at row 2593. But I wonder if I can use limit and offset to handle this.

Comment: Update: This line is throwing that error,   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

Comment: is this the issue, Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);?